# Preferable method filtering a LinkedList

Tags: java

Classes TestListRemoveFunctional & TestListRemoveUpdateState perform filtering at runtime of a LinkedList.

I think the TestListRemoveFunctional implementation is cleaner as it does not update state, but is less efficient as it creates a new List at each filtering step.

Although TestListRemoveFunctional & TestListRemoveUpdateState essentially perform same job, TestListRemoveFunctional is preferable as it does not update state, unlike filtering implementation in TestListRemoveUpdateState.

Please note I'm limited to not using java8 lambdas or project Guava lambdas.

Can confirm my assertion that TestListRemoveFunctional is preferable ?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class TestListRemoveFunctional {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        TestListRemoveFunctional t = new TestListRemoveFunctional();
        LinkedList<MyObj> l = new LinkedList<MyObj>();
        l.add(new MyObj("1"));
        l.add(new MyObj("2"));

        System.out.println("size : "+l.size());

        LinkedList<MyObj> f1 = t.filterItem1(l);
        System.out.println("size : "+f1.size());

        LinkedList<MyObj> f2 = t.filterItem2(f1);
        System.out.println("size : "+f2.size());
    }

    private LinkedList<MyObj> filterItem1(LinkedList<MyObj> l) {

        LinkedList<MyObj> toReturn = new LinkedList<MyObj>();
        for (MyObj myObj : l) {

            if (!myObj.param.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                toReturn.add(myObj);
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    private LinkedList<MyObj> filterItem2(LinkedList<MyObj> l) {

        LinkedList<MyObj> toReturn = new LinkedList<MyObj>();
        for (MyObj myObj : l) {

            if (!myObj.param.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                System.out.println(myObj.param);
                toReturn.add(myObj);
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }



    private static class MyObj {

        public String param;

        public MyObj(String param) {
            this.param = param;
        }
    }

}

********************************************************************************************


import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class TestListRemoveUpdateState {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        TestListRemoveUpdateState t = new TestListRemoveUpdateState();
        LinkedList<MyObj> l = new LinkedList<MyObj>();
        l.add(new MyObj("1"));
        l.add(new MyObj("2"));

        System.out.println("size is : " + l.size());

        t.filterItem1(l);       
        System.out.println("size is : " + l.size());

        t.filterItem2(l);   
        System.out.println("size is : " + l.size());
    }

    private void filterItem1(LinkedList<MyObj> l) {

        Iterator<MyObj> iter = l.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            MyObj myObj = iter.next();

            if (myObj.param.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    private void filterItem2(LinkedList<MyObj> l) {

        Iterator<MyObj> iter = l.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            MyObj myObj = iter.next();

            if (myObj.param.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class MyObj {

        public String param;

        public MyObj(String param) {
            this.param = param;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the advantage of linked lists is to have a very efficient `remove` operation.

Let us consider the following linked list (in java, linked lists are actually doubly linked list):

```
e1 <-> e2 <-> e3 <-> e4 <-> e5
```

If you want to remove `e3`, all you have to do is:

```
e3.previous.next = e3.next;
e3.next.previous = e3.previous;
e3.next = null;
e3.previous = null;
e3.element = null;
```

And that is exactly what `iterator.remove()` does.

Therefore, `TestListRemoveUpdateState` is more efficient, because you are handling `LinkedList`

---

As a side note, the preferred method on an `ArrayList` would be `TestListRemoveFunctional`.

If you were to filter on `ArrayList`, then  `TestListRemoveFunctional` than would be more efficient than `TestListRemoveUpdateState` because the remove operation on `ArrayList` recreates a complete backing array every time it is being called (even though System.arrayCopy is **very** efficient).

Comment: though if you were to filter on an ArrayList you wouldn't use remove but swap-out the dropped elements instead (to be removed on a final resize) thus again being very efficient

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. You're comparing the performance of `remove` between a linked list and an array list, whereas the question is about removing an element from a list using two approaches: as you are iterating through it vs. creating a new list with filtered items.

Comment: @VivinPaliath No I am not comparing the efficiency between ``ArrayList`` and ``LinkedList``, I just added a side note to show the preferred method would be different on an ``ArrayList``.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios That is exactly what his ``TestListRemoveFunctional`` is doing. Hence exactly what I am saying.

Comment: No you're not, my example is in-place (as in my example does not allocate)

Comment: Ok but you cannot do it on an ``ArrayList`` since you cannot access the backing array and the list is constantly resizing. And how would do a "final resize" without not allocating a new array anyway?

Answer (score 2):

What's preferable? To keep the state of the original item or efficiency? To justify any choice between those classes you've got to state which trait you deem most important, because you're not having one without the other.
BTW, both has a few flaws as for efficiency goes as well as readability

UPDATE

(Readability) instead of two methods for filtering (one for item 1, one for item 2), only one method is needed: List<T> filterItem (List<T> l, T item)

(Reusability) Use generics instead of particular types. Instead of <MyObj>, declare them as <T>. This way you can use those classes and methods with lists of any component.

If you declare the parameters as List instead of LinkedList you increase the usability of those methods.

(Flexibility) If you declare the return type as List you're able to change the particular implementation of List you want to use while avoiding the users of your classes to have to re-write their code.

It'd be even better to use a "filter" class like commons-collections

(Efficiency) in your particular implementation of the filter methods you're using equalsIgnoreCase with strings that are no case-sensitive, you can just use equals in that case.

(Safety) Lists can contain null, depending on the implementation. In particular, LinkedList can, so there's the risk of NullPointerException in those filters both by accessing to an element of the list and when accessing to he value of MyObj.param.

Comment: can you elaborate on these flaws excluding exposing MyObj.param as public ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "preferable". Removing an element from a list while you are iterating through it, is safely done by using the iterator (as you are doing).

If you look at your other approach, then yes, you are creating a new linked list. In the worst case, you end up using `O(2*n)` space if you don't end up filtering anything. So it depends on whether you are comfortable using more memory.

I think the first approach is fine since per the documentation, using `iterator.remove()` is perfectly safe. It would only be unsafe if you cannot guarantee that the collection will be modified by someone else at the same time (i.e., concurrent access).